# Annotation @Transactional does not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, transactional

I am trying to use the annotation @Transactional to access my MySQL using Hibernate, Spring and JSF. My problem is:

When I use the annotation @Transactional at my managedBean to make a query I got this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
at br.com.rpg.DAO.AbstractDAO.getCurrentSession(AbstractDAO.java:14)
at br.com.rpg.DAO.CountryDAO.findAll(CountryDAO.java:14)
at br.com.rpg.managedBeans.SignupBean.init(SignupBean.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code and xml config is:

**application-config.xml**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.rpg.DO" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.rpg" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**My MB**

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class SignupBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1787096549063029840L;

    @Inject
    private CountryDAO country;

    @Inject
    private UserDAO user;

    private Map<String, Integer> countries;

    private Integer selected;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void init() {
        List<CountryDO> findAll = country.findAll();
        countries = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (CountryDO countryDO : findAll) {
            countries.put(countryDO.getName(), countryDO.getId());
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public void setCountries(Map<String, Integer> countries) {
        this.countries = countries;
    }

    public Integer getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Integer selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
```

My Country DAO has the @Named annotation. Someone could help me?

Thx.

Comment: `@Named` is a CDI artifact and `@Scope` is a Spring artifact - a nasty combination - something which cannot be relied upon. Isn't it? `@Transactional`, on the other hand, is a different thing which is to be used on the service layer. I have, however, chosen to remain silent about it.

Answer (score 2):

you have applied `@PostConstruct` and `@Transactional`  on `init` method. `init` method would be called before applying any AOP Proxy interceptor is applied because of `@PostConstruct`. Hence at the time of invoking `init` there is no transaction proxy applied. if you need to call init method on Application startup use `ApplicationEvent`